# How do I set SCM for Maven in pom.xml when my repositories are not public?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-central

I'm working on a Java library that is in a private company GitLab repo. It's part of an SDK to be used by customers. I'm trying to figure out how to publish this to Maven Central and I'm stuck on setting the SCM fields in pom.xml.

What do I set these fields to when the repository is not publicly available?

I need something like this:

```
  <!-- Define where the source code for this project lives -->
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/evansiroky/maven-semantic-release-example.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/evansiroky/maven-semantic-release-example.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/evansiroky/maven-semantic-release-example</url>
  </scm>
```

Comment: What is the issue or error?

Comment: Scm is a required and I don't know what to set these fields to. All the examples I've seen are publicly readable repositories.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. When you try with the configuration you shared, is there an actual issue or error?

Comment: I had not tried it yet as I didn't know what to set these fields. I was able to ultimately just set the smc URLs to my private repo and it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SCM fields can point to a private repository and the URL can point to a website.

I ended up doing this:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://private-repo.com/private-repo.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://private-repo.com/private-repo.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://docs.mywebsite.com</url>
  </scm>
```